# Bootstrap navbar: How to have an active navbar item dropdown on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen a lot written about how to have a Bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than when clicking on it. Unfortunately, I have not been able to make this work if the menu link is "active" for a given page.

I cannot share the site I'm working on or code samples from the site, but here is a navbar example very similar to what I have: https://codepen.io/betdream/pen/frDqh

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

except imagine "Dropdown" was also linked to a page. When the user is on the "Dropdown" page the "Dropdown" menu head will be active and then the menu hover effect breaks. Note: The site I'm working on is Django-based (it's effectively a web-based desktop application) and I use a block statement in the "Dropdown" page's html to make the "Dropdown" menu link appear "active":

```
{% block %}<li class="active"><a href="link">Dropdown</a>{% endblock %}
```

Clicking on "Dropdown" will bring you to the "Dropdown" page, making the "Dropdown" part of the navbar active, so the hover effect needs to work or the user will not be able to access "Dropdown" menu.

**How does one get the dropdown menu to continue working with the hover effect even when the menu head is active?** Does Bootstrap's javascript interfere somehow?